# Reporting Service Web Service MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, reporting-services

We are building an MVC application, we need to render some SSRS reports, so we are trying to use Reporting Services Web Service for this purpose, looking for some documentation of SOAP API I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx), so I tried to replicate that code and write my own controller, but as you can see I don't return any ActionResult, I don't know what should I return.

So my questions are, which is the best way to use Reporting Service Web Service in an MVC application? What should I return in case rs.Render is success?

```
    public ActionResult soapReport(string path)
    {
        soapSSRS.ReportExecutionService rs = new soapSSRS.ReportExecutionService();
        rs.Url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";
        ;
        rs.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ssrs_user"].ToString(), 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ssrs_pass"].ToString(), 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ssrs_domain"].ToString());

        // Render arguments
        byte[] result = null;
        string reportPath = "/MyReportFolder/MyReport";
        string format = "MHTML";
        string historyID = null;
        string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

        // Prepare report parameter.
        soapSSRS.ParameterValue[] parameters = new soapSSRS.ParameterValue[3];
        parameters[0] = new soapSSRS.ParameterValue();
        parameters[0].Name = "token";
        parameters[0].Value = "XxXxXxXxXxXxXx";

        DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
        string showHideToggle = null;
        string encoding;
        string mimeType;
        string extension;
        soapSSRS.Warning[] warnings = null;
        ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;

        soapSSRS.ExecutionInfo execInfo = new soapSSRS.ExecutionInfo();
        soapSSRS.ExecutionHeader execHeader = new soapSSRS.ExecutionHeader();

        rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

        execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

        rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");
        String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

        try
        {
            result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is 2-step process.

First step is to generate report - this is what you code does. What I do in this step (step is initiated in AJAX call) is to save file report locally with unique name and then return JsonResult with code indicating generating report was successful, local file name and desired remote file name.

Then this JsonResult is parsed in .success handler of AJAX call and another Action will be called  to download the file. This is a good example: [How To Create And Download File in ASP.Net MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1156485/How-to-Create-and-Download-File-with-Ajax-in-ASP-N)